# python error get object value

Tags: python

I'm a bit new in programming with python, but I have do this code:

```
dimValue = 0
```

........

```
elif event[0] == "control" and body["location"] == location and body["action"] == "on":
    auxValue = int(body["dim"])
    print("AuxValue = " + str(auxValue))
    if auxValue > dimValue:
        print("entrou")
        dimControl=auxValue-dimValue
        print("DimControl = " + str(dimControl))
        dimValue = auxValue
        os.system("heyu bright A1 "+ str(dimControl))
    elif dimValue > auxValue:
        print("saiu")
        dimControl=dimValue-auxValue
        dimValue = auxValue
        os.system("heyu dim A1 "+ str(dimControl))
```

With this code, if int(body["dim"]) is 5, just show the first print, and don't enter in the if else statement. If I comment this line "dimValue = auxValue", it enters in the if else, and do everything well. But I need to put this line. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Hugo Silva

Comment: The very top of your source is an `elif`.  I think you have a loop or something else going on that could explain your problem.  For example you are changing `dimValue` within the above code.  If you have a loop, then you may be losing control of your state.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But I need to change the dimValue somewhere with auxValue, Where I can do this?

Comment: With the information here, I can only recommend to separate taking action from changing state.  Have one method to change state, and one to act on new information.  That way you are in better control of the time order of these things.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like neither the `if` block nor the `elif` block are being entered. This probably occurs when auxValue equals dimValue; then neither of the criteria evaluate to true. You could change > to >= or change < to <=, depending on which block you want to run when they are equal.

Comment: No, you should just use `else` instead of `elif`.

Comment: In the first case that this event is called, auxValue is 5 and dimValue is 0.